# Geogebra resizing shapes without copying

Tags: geometrydrawing

How do I resize a shape without making a copy and using dilate from point?

[How my shape with vectors looks like](http://www.dropbox.com/s/a7soic3p2763aky/gg.png)

How do I limit the axes range for exporting?

How do I define a size, say 3 cm for cropping a portion of the graphics view for export?

Also, is there any software for making simulated graphs without any real data? I'm doing image processing and need to make mock-ups such as temporal segments and histograms.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is out of scope of stackoverflow and should be asked in https://help.geogebra.org , but I'll try anyway.

1) You can right-click the graphics view and set the dimensions in there. The export will take the current graphics view. Or you can select part of Graphics using the mouse before export. Or use points Export_1, Export_2 as described here

2) You define cropping of graphics view in one of the ways described above to eg. 6 units, then set the export scale to 0.5cm per unit

3) You can do random functions in GeoGebra directly, eg.

```
Function[Join[{0,5},Sequence[3*sin(k)+RandomUniform[0, 1],k,0,5,0.1]]]
```